# How to set color of iPhones top bar?

Tags: html, css, iphone

I have a website (written in HTML and CSS) with a header in blue.

Now I want, that the top bar next to the notch of iPhones becomes blue as well.

Take this example, where the iPhones top bar is red as well as the pages header.

[image]

Instead of this the top bar about the webpage is grey.

Is there any advice for this issue?

Comment: I don't understand your problem, what happens when you put your header with a blue background ?

Comment: I updated the question with a picture, that shows the issue

Comment: Can you cite a source that indicates that webpages are given this same level of control of Safari’s interface as natively-deployed apps do (what you seem to cite in your first screenshot)? The capabilities of each are fundamentally different for very good UX and security reasons.

Comment: No I don't have a source. I didn't know, that there seems to be no possibility for the wanted behavior..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like you want to use a meta tag with the name `theme-color`. To make the top the color `#39ff14` you can add this in the head section of your html:

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#39ff14"/>
```

However, this attribute only works on some browsers ([can I use](https://caniuse.com/?search=theme-color)).

Answer (score -3):

set "margin-top: 1px;" for the top element, then iphone will use your website/app background-color.