# Customise theme on iOS Smart Banners

Tags: ios, safari, app-store

I've read several things now that tell me that I cannot customise the colours or content of a smart banner. However, I have seen several websites with what I believe is a genuine smart banner, but with their themes.

Check out deliveroo.co.uk (with the app installed, screenshot) and you see the smart banner at the top (and then a clearly not-working knockoff underneath).

I'm almost positive that this is the real smart banner, because:

1. It has the same physical structure, albeit with custom colours
2. If I inspect it on safari, it doesn't appear in the HTML (the first element is the knockoff one below it).

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it is a custom made banner using regular HTML. I was able to find it in the DOM

[image]

When looking at your screenshot i see there are 2 banners. The first one is the one your iPhone provides. If your phone detects the app is installed it will show the `open` banner and not the `install` banner. the iphone logic would never show both banners, it's either the install or the open one.

Also the html classes of that banner matches other elements on the page. So it's just custom build in the page

I had to implement smart banners as well and the standard iPhone options were very limited when it came to customisation.

Comment: You're talking about the one I described as "clearly not-working knockoff underneath". I'm talking about the one above it, that has deliveroo colours but is otherwise a native smart banner. The question is, how do I achieve *that* banner?

Comment: deliveroo has this meta tag `<meta name="theme-color" content="#009e99">`. Maybe the iPhone is looking at that to set the color at the top and the banner.

Answer (score 0):

Try [changing the accent color of your page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70932336/19330634) like so :

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#39ff14"/>
```

Your app button's background and font color should change then.

However, you cannot customize any other element inside the banner according to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/promoting_apps_with_smart_app_banners).