how to make the background display full screen (Safari)
On Safari phones, I get a terrible white stripe on top. I would like it to be filled with background

For example, on this site, there is no such strip on top

HTML file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover">
    <title>Авторизация</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/login.css?v=1.1.4">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-border active">
    </div>
</body>
</html>

CSS file:
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
}

html, body {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, hsl(250, 15%, 30%), hsl(250, 15%, 10%));
}

body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}


Could you please use  <> (Javascript/HTML/CSS snippet) to modify the code you are asking and the expected status to a executable form?

I don't have Safari, so I can't test this myself; if you use: height: 100dvh; or height: 100lvh; does the problem resolve? Or, possibly, try to use min-height: 100vh; (testing the lvh and dvh units also). Documentation for viewport units: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Values_and_Units#viewport_units

@DavidThomas Unfortunately, it didn't affect anything. :(

I think it depends on the ios settings... https://allthings.how/how-to-show-safari-search-bar-at-top-on-iphone-running-ios-15/ It won't be easy?

I think most of them fill in similar colors with theme colors. Do you want to check? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70856591/how-to-set-color-of-iphones-top-bar

I suppose you mean changing the color of the status bar?
Try to add apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style meta tag. You can checkout the 'Changing the Status Bar Appearance' of this page
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">

Or, you can try to add theme-color meta tag. theme-color

Yes!!! This is exactly what I need.
There's just one small problem.
I use a gradient in the background. I made the theme color #454158, like the top of the gradient.  But at the bottom, if you pull the page up, the same color appears and the gradient from below is broken. It's not that critical, but is it possible to fix it too? I'm sorry for my English

@EFERYEG The only way to fix it is to change the color manually when scrolling. Maybe adjusting the page design to make it unscrollable is a better pratice.

I checked it on safari.
images

Code


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
}

html {
  padding-top: env(safe-area-inset-top);
  }

html, body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, hsl(250, 15%, 30%), hsl(250, 15%, 10%));
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="hsl(250, 15%, 30%)"/>
    <title>Авторизация</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-border active">
    </div>
</body>
</html>




Super! Thank you very much)
Is it also possible to make sure that the page is not scroll? I have only one element in the middle of the page with a button. In Safari, it is not located in the middle, but a little lower. And the page can be scrolled down a bit
height: 100dvh solves this problem, but I don't know if it is the right thing to do. Maybe there are better options to make the page static

No, theme-color just sets it to a color similar to the page content and doesn't change with scrolling. If it's a design with a fixed header at the top, but... @EFERYEG
